# Perl: Connecting to Walmart API to load items Unsupported Media type error

Tags: perl, walmart-api

We are trying using the marketplace.walmartapis.com api to bulk list items and it is returning unsupported media type for xml item feed

We are using Perl and are able to perform other commands to update inventory and pricing, check orders, lookup feeds and skus etc. The token SHOULD be good, as we ran two calls back to back using the same token and the first call (item inventory) worked as expected before trying to send the xml file. It is only when we try to send the xml batch file that we run into the problem.

We assume the issue is with the header/authentication and have tried many different combinations. But obviously we are missing something.

What is being sent:

```
POST https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds?feedType=item HTTP/1.1
```

Headers:

```http
Authorization: Basic MDc4......
Content-Length: 2277
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: multipart/formdata
Host: marketplace.walmartapis.com
WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: TB123456V32
WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN: eyJra...
WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace
Boundary: 1234ran4321dom5678boundary
```

formdata payload:

```xml
--1234ran4321dom5678boundary
Content-Disposition: formdata; name="xml"
Content-length: 2151


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPItemFeed xmlns="http://walmart.com/">
  <MPItemFeedHeader>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <requestBatchId>......</requestBatchId>
    <feedDate>2019-02-18T19:45:17</feedDate>
    <mart>WALMART_US</mart>
  </MPItemFeedHeader>
  <MPItem>
    <processMode>CREATE</processMode>
    <sku>....</sku>
    <productIdentifiers>
      <productIdentifier>
        <productIdType>UPC</productIdType>
        <productId>..........</productId>
      </productIdentifier>
    </productIdentifiers>
    <MPProduct>
      <productName>.....................</productName>
      <category>
        <SportAndRecreation>
          <SportAndRecreationOther>
            <shortDescription>........................</shortDescription>
            <keyFeatures>
              <keyFeaturesValue>I...............</keyFeaturesValue>
            </keyFeatures>
            <brand>............</brand>
            <manufacturer>.............</manufacturer>
            <manufacturerPartNumber>.............</manufacturerPartNumber>
            <modelNumber>..</modelNumber>
            <mainImageUrl>............</mainImageUrl>
            <count>1</count>
            <isProp65WarningRequired>No</isProp65WarningRequired>
            <sportsLeague>
               <sportsLeagueValue>....</sportsLeagueValue>
            </sportsLeague>
            <keywords>................</keywords>
            <isMemorabilia>......</isMemorabilia>
            <isCollectible>...........</isCollectible>
          </SportAndRecreationOther>
        </SportAndRecreation>
      </category>
    </MPProduct>
    </MPOffer>
        <price>21.95</price>
        <StartDate>2019-02-23T19:45:17</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2019-04-19T19:45:17</EndDate>
        <ShippingWeight>
          <measure>2</measure>
          <unit>lb</unit>
        </ShippingWeight>
        <ProductTaxCode>2038345</ProductTaxCode>
    </MPOffer>
  </MPItem>
</MPItemFeed>
--1234ran4321dom5678boundary--
```

back from Walmart.pm

```perl
$HASH = {
      "error" => {
                 "category" => "DATA",
                 "causes" => {},
                 "code" => "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE.GMP_GATEWAY_API",
                 "errorIdentifiers" => {},
                 "info" => "Unsupported Media Type.",
                 "severity" => "ERROR"
               },
      "xmlns:ns2" => "http://walmart.com/"
};
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Link to docs, please?

Comment: Are you sure it wants a form and not just the XML doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that looked. The problem seems to be solved

It was one minor typo

multipart/formdata needed to be multipart/form-data

With that change now we are getting a feed id that shows up in the Seller area

Comment: Would you look at that, [their documentation](https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#bulkCreateUpdateItems) says `multipart/formdata`.  That's wrong.  You should report that to them, I bet they'd appreciate it.